# How to export multiple object from files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a list off foods and drinks that I want to export from a file like this:

```
// example.js
var foods = ['', ''];
var drinks = ['', ''];
```

I would like to export those, so I can import them as:

```
import {foods, drinks} from './example.js'
console.log(foods); // ['', '']
```

My question is, how should I export them in the first example to get them in the second example

Usually I export one object from a file and that works, but multiple I am not sure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can export multiple objects like this in ES6 :

```
// example.js
var foods = ['', ''];
var drinks = ['', ''];

export {
    foods,
    drinks
}
```

Then, when importing you do it like this :

```
import { foods, drinks } from './example.js';
```

For more info, check this [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

Answer (score 12):

```
// example.js
export const foods = [...
export const drinks = [...
```

Use the `export` keyword, and by not including the `default` keyword, your import code should work just as you submitted it.